# Find and replace using wildcard/regex characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, wildcards

I have an HTML Code with the following structure:

```
        <td class="tar">
      <div class="bubble in">
        Some Text, I want to keep! And maybe even an image: <img src=
        "12345.png" width="22" height="22" alt="0" class="example" /><br />
        <span class="time"><div style="text-align:right">17:14</span></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="tal">
      <div class="bubble out">
        Some Text, I want to keep!<br />
        <span class="time"><div style="text-align:right">17:15</span></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

This is the structure of a chat with the two particiopants "bubble in" and "bubble out".
Now I want to extend the timecode of the "bubble in" with an image.

Here ist what I came up with:

Find what:

```
<div class="bubble in">[^"]*<span class="time"><div style="text-align:right">([0-9]*[0-9]*):([0-9]*[0-9]*)</span></div>
```

Replace with:

```
<div class="bubble in">\1<span class="time"><div style="text-align:right">\2\3\4\5\6&#160<img src= "test.png" width="16" height="10" alt="0"/
```

The searching works but replacing \1 doesn't work somehow. Can you help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `\1` doesn't work because you aren't capturing that group - you would need to put parentheses around it.
But, it seems that there are more problems... When I try it in Notepad++ with your example it doesn't find a match, and I wouldn't expect it to.

Your current pattern looks for the bubble in open div tag, followed by any number of characters that are not double-quotes, followed by the time span tag. In your example you have double-quotes in the img tag first, so it doesn't match.
In the time capturing part, there are also some strange things going on: your `[0-9]*` means any number of occurrences of digits 0-9, but then you repeat it. I'm guessing that you really just wanted 0-9 twice, followed by a colon, followed by two more.

So:
    `<div class="bubble in">(.*?)<span class="time"><div style="text-align:right">([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})</span></div>`

The `.*?` will non-greedily look for matches. But, if a bubble in div doesn't have the time span then it is going to go right on out of that div and into anything else until it finds a time span. Hopefully that is something you can cope with, otherwise it gets really complicated. The `[0-9]{2}` tells the regex that you want exactly two. If you don't have leading zeros on times, then change it to `{1,2}` which will look for between one and two.

Finally, in your replace - there are now 3 captured groups... The "Some text, I want to keep!...", the hours and the minutes. So `\4\5\6` aren't present.  Oh, and don't forget to tick the <kbd>. matches newline</kbd> option, or you won't match either (at least from your example).

Good luck!